# str.erase(); doesn't work inside a function

Tags: c++

I have a code here that ignores comment lines. The thing is, i tried creating a function with what i had so that i can use it later anywhere within my code. But i am encountering a problem. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string comment(string str);

int main ()
{
  string str;
  cout << "Enter the string> ";
  getline( cin, str );
  comment(str);
  cout << str << "\n";

  return 0;
}

string comment(string str)
{

  unsigned found = str.find('#');
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    str.erase(found);
  else
    return(str);           

  return(str);

}
```

Sample input:(from keyboard)
    Enter the string> my name is #comment

output i am getting:

```
my name is #comment
```

output i am supposed to get:

```
my name is
```

Also if i use the same code without the function, i get the correct answer. And here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str;

  cout << "Enter the string> ";
  getline( cin, str );
  unsigned found = str.find('#');
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    str.erase(found);


  cout << str << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass your string by reference

```
void comment(string& str)
^^^^                 ^^^
```

OR receive the returned value from the function.

```
getline( cin, str );
str = comment(str);
^^^
```

Otherwise the function receives a **copy** of your string. Any modifications you do `str` while inside the `comment` function is not visible in `main`.

Comment: @BrownieTuffy Just FYI If you pass by reference then you don't need to return anything.